# How to authenticate cypress-mailhog request. 401 status code

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing, mailhog

I am using cypress and mailhog to test email validation step of the sign up process on our staging site. Currently the test is failing with a `401` status code - the mailhog inbox requires a username and password.

How can I pass a username and password into the API request?

I have followed installation, setup and usage steps in the [cypress-mailhog docs](https://github.com/SMenigat/cypress-mailhog).

Comment: In the default installation, I did not need to specify a username and a password. The server just catches all E-Mails. Can you open the web interface on http://localhost:8025/ without credentials?

Comment: This worked
`            cy.request({
                method:'GET',
                url:'https://staging.example.com',
                auth: {
                    'user': 'user',
                    'password': 'password'
                }`
(Didn't use cypress-mailhog in the end)